# Sales Order Grid Mass Action Route 404 Error

Tags: magento2, order-grid, massaction

I have created module to send email using mass actions, but it is showing 404 error.

> etc/acl.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores">
                    <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores_settings">
                        <resource id="Magento_Config::config">
                            <resource id="Vendor_MassEmailCustomers::massemailcustomers_configuration" title="Mass Email Customers Section" />
                        </resource>
                    </resource>
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

> view/adminhtml/ui_components/sales_order_grid.xml

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <action name="mass_email_rx">
                <settings>
                    <confirm>
                        <message translate="true">Are you sure to send Rx Missing Email to the selected customers?</message>
                        <title translate="true">Send Rx Missing Email</title>
                    </confirm>
                    <url path="massemailcustomers/email/rxSend"/>
                    <type>mass_email_rx</type>
                    <label translate="true">Send Rx Missing Email</label>
                </settings>
            </action>
            
        </massaction>
    </listingToolbar>
</listing>
```

> etc/adminhtml/routes.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="massemailcustomers" frontName="massemailcustomers">
            <module name="Vendor_MassEmailCustomers" before="Magento_Backend" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

> Conroller/Adminhtml/Email/RxSend.php

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\MassEmailCustomers\Controller\Adminhtml\Email;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface;
use Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\CollectionFactory as CustomerCollectionFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory as SalesCollectionFactory;
use Vendor\MassEmailCustomers\Model\Config;
use Magento\Framework\App\Area;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\MailException;
use Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect;

class RxSend extends Action
{
    /**
     * @var Filter
     */
    protected $filter;

    /**
     * @var salesCollectionFactory
     */
    protected $salesCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * @var CustomerCollectionFactory
     */
    protected $customerCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * @var Config
     */
    protected $config;

    /**
     * @var TransportBuilder
     */
    protected $transportBuilder;

    /**
     * @var StateInterface
     */
    protected $inlineTranslation;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Filter $filter
     * @param Config $config
     * @param CustomerCollectionFactory $customerCollectionFactory
     * @param SalesCollectionFactory $salesCollectionFactory
     * @param TransportBuilder $transportBuilder
     * @param StateInterface $inlineTranslation
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Filter $filter,
        Config $config,
        CustomerCollectionFactory $customerCollectionFactory,
        SalesCollectionFactory $salesCollectionFactory,
        TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        StateInterface $inlineTranslation
    ) {
        $this->filter = $filter;
        $this->config = $config;
        $this->customerCollectionFactory = $customerCollectionFactory;
        $this->salesCollectionFactory = $salesCollectionFactory;
        $this->transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Execute action
     *
     * @return Redirect
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        var_dump("rx email to send");
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Clear your cahec and remove generated/*

Comment: Steps done so far (1) rm -rf generated/* (2) bin/magento s:d:c (3) bin/magento c:f (4) Removed browser cache and used incognito window, but still showing 404 error

Answer (score 0):

Please Run below command and check once

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

> this will generates DI configuration and all missing classes that can
> be auto-generated

Comment: Done this many time still same 404 error

Comment: make sure your rule has permission to access this controller

Comment: I have added acl.xml also, check my updated question.

Comment: Don't know what was the issue behind it, but since I was using Bitnami VM so stopped the VM and started again and 404 error disappeared now and the code is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I think it because your controller did not return correct type. Controller should return type page `Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory` if you want to use this url as a page.

if it's only a execute controller you can handle logic and return redirect to another page.
DI `Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory` and then `return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('*/*/');`

Hope it help

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the issue was 404, and apparently it was related to the router before reaching to controller execute method. However, issue is resolved now after I restarted the Bitnami VM.